# Access to XMLHttpRequest at has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, express, cors

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
    header: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}));

app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
        res.redirect('/');
    });
//Routes

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: 'clientID',
        clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            return cb(err, user);
        });

    }
));

//Start server
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('start server');
})`

app.js

    const authentication = () => {
        axios( {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback',
        }).then((res) => console.log(res.data));
    }

Перепробовал разные варианты с header, ничего не помогло
```

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=access-control-allow-origin+is%3Aq)

Comment: Ну у себя-то вы заголовки CORS отдали, но гугл-то тут при чём?

Comment: И палить `clientSecret` в вопросе не самая умная идея

Comment: и `callbackURL` с localhost - не самая умная идея

Comment: вы для начала с портом определитесь